# How to pass const pointer to const object using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I want to pass a `unique_ptr` to a helper function, and I want to make sure that the helper function neither modifies the pointer, nor the pointed object. Without the `unique_ptr`, the solution is to have

```
void takePtr(AClass const * const aPtr) {
  // Do something with *aPtr. 
  // We cannot change aPtr, not *aPtr. 
}
```

(Well, technically, `AClass const * aPtr` is enough.) And I can call this with

```
AClass * aPtr2 = new AClass(3);
takePtr(aPtr2);
```

I want to instead use `unique_ptr`, but cannot figure out how to write this. I tried

```
void takeUniquePtr(unique_ptr<AClass const> const & aPtr) {
  // Access *aPtr, but should not be able to change aPtr, or *aPtr. 
}
```

When I call this with

```
unique_ptr<AClass> aPtr(new AClass(3));
takeUniquePtr(aPtr);
```

it does not compile. The error I see is

```
testcpp/hello_world.cpp:141:21: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘std::unique_ptr<AClass>’ to ‘const std::unique_ptr<const AClass>&’ [-fpermissive]
```

Shouldn't the conversion from `unique_ptr<AClass>` to `unique_ptr<AClass const>` be automatic? What am I missing here?

By the way, if I change `unique_ptr<AClass const> const & aPtr` to `unique_ptr<AClass> const & aPtr` in the function definition, it compiles, but then I can call functions like `aPtr->changeAClass()`, which I don't want to allow.

Comment: Why not pass a const reference, then? (instead of a `unique_ptr`)

Comment: Marshall Clow: I happen to have `unique_ptr`s around in the code. I can dereference the pointer and pass as const reference, but that is not ideal, given the code base I am working with. Also, sometimes, the `unique_ptr` might point to NULL in my case (not managing any object), so const reference will not work in that case.

Comment: In that case, I would just pass a `const AClass *`. No need for the callee to know that it's in a `unique_ptr`. Why couple that tightly?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  If you pass a `unique_ptr` to the helper, it will by definition free the object when its done with it -- that's the whole point of `unique_ptr`.  If you don't want that, why not just pass a regular (const) pointer?

Comment: @ChrisDodd: notice he passes a *reference* to `unique_ptr`, so the object will live on when the helper is done.

Comment: Marshall Clow: I might need to do that. `.get()` the unique_ptr, and pass the raw pointer as const pointer to const object.

Comment: @MarshallClow: But another question remains: Why is compiler not able to cast from `unique_ptr<A>` to `unique_ptr<A const>`? (Implicit) non-const to const conversion happens all the time! :-)

Comment: Yes, it does - `T` and `const T` but are very different from `class<T>` and `class<const T>`. In the first case, the two classes are the same, one just is marked const (there's even a set of template metafunctions for conversion `add_const` and `remove_const`. In the second case, there's no way the compiler can be sure that the classes are in any way related (except by name). I can specialize a template for const types and have it be *completely* different than for non-const types.

Comment: Just pass a reference to const object.  It doesn't make much sense to pass a pointer at all (unless there's some reason it needs to be a pointer, and you haven't said there is)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Smart pointers are for managing ownership and lifetime, they allow us (amongst other things) to safely transfer ownership around the various parts of our code.

When you pass a `const unique_ptr<T>&` to a function (irrelevant of whether `T` is `const` or not), what it actually means is that the function promises to never modify the `unique_ptr` itself (but it could still modify the pointed-to object if `T` is not `const`) ie. there will be no possible transfer of ownership whatsoever. You're just using the `unique_ptr` as a useless wrapper around a naked pointer.

So, as @MarshallClow suggested in a comment, you should just get rid of the wrapper and pass either a naked pointer or a direct reference. What's cool with this is that your code is now **semantically clear** (your function's signature clearly states that it does not mess with ownership, which was **not** immediately obvious with a `const unique_ptr<...>&`) and it solves your "constification" problem at the same time!

Namely:

```
void someFunction(const AClass* p) { ... }

std::unique_ptr<AClass> ptr(new AClass());
someFunction(ptr.get());
```

---

**Edit:** to address your secondary question "*why won't the compiler let me ... cast `unique_ptr<A>` to `unique_ptr<A const>`?*".

Actually, you can *move* a `unique_ptr<A>` to a `unique_ptr<A const>`:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A());
std::unique_ptr<const A> q(std::move(p));
```

But as you can see this means a transfer of ownership from `p` to `q`.

The problem with your code is that you're passing a (reference to) `unique_ptr<const A>` *to a function*. Since there is a type discrepancy with `unique_ptr<A>`, to make it work the compiler needs to instantiate a temporary. But unless you transfer ownership manually by using `std::move`, the compiler will try to **copy** your `unique_ptr` and it can't do that since `unique_ptr` explicitly forbids it.

Notice how the problem goes away if you move the `unique_ptr`:

```
void test(const std::unique_ptr<const int>& p) { ... }

std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
test(std::move(p));
```

The compiler is now able to construct a temporary `unique_ptr<const A>` and move the original `unique_ptr<A>` without breaking your expectations (since it is now clear that you want to move, not copy).

**So, the root of the problem is that `unique_ptr` only has move semantics not copy semantics, but you'd need the copy semantics to create a temporary *and* yet keep ownership afterwards.** Egg and chicken, `unique_ptr` just isn't designed that way.

If you now consider `shared_ptr` which **has** copy semantics, the problem also disappears.

```
void test(const std::shared_ptr<const int>& p) { ... }

std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
test(p);
//^^^^^ Works!
```

The reason is that the compiler is now able to create a temporary `std::shared_ptr<const int>` **copy** (automatically casting from `std::shared_ptr<int>`) and bind that temporary to a `const` reference.

I guess this more or less covers it, even though my explanation lacks standardese lingo and is perhaps not as clear as it should be. :)

Comment: In the second paragraph, as you mentioned, the function "promises" to never modify the object. I guess the question is why won't the compiler let me make a guarantee around that, by allowing me to cast `unique_ptr<A>` to `unique_ptr<A const>`? I am guessing I am missing something here. Most of the time, C++ disallows things for a good reason, no? :-)

Comment: What I meant by `object` was the `unique_ptr` itself, not necessarily the pointed-to object. I realize this does not address the question in your comment, but I thought I'd still clarify (and I will edit my question accordingly). As to the question, well, I agree that "*intuitively*" one should be able to cast from `unique_ptr<A>` to `unique_ptr<const A>` (but obviously not the other way around). But as you say, C++ probably has a good reason for that, we just have to find it. ;)

Comment: @YogeshwerSharma: I edited my answer to address the issue. TLDR; you can't create a temporary copy of a `unique_ptr` because it only has move semantics.

Comment: syam: That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time explain this. It is quite clear. 

The only missing piece in my mind is whether there is really an instantiation of a temporary happening here? I printed something in the constructor of the class, and then passed `shared_ptr<A>` to a function accepting `shared_ptr<A const>` and seems like there is no constructor being called. Is this consistent with your understanding?

Comment: @YogeshwerSharma: "*I printed something in the constructor of the class*" => if you mean your pointed-to class, then yes it's consistent: the temporary is a `shared_ptr` object, the pointed-to object stays the same for both original `shared_ptr<A>` and temporary `shared_ptr<const A>`. To observe the temporary you'd have to hack the source of `shared_ptr` and add a trace in its constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Got to this old question on const smart pointers.
Above answers ignore the simple template solution.

### The very simple template option (option a)

```
template<class T>
void foo(const unique_ptr<T>& ptr) {
    // do something with ptr
}
```

this solution allows all possible options of unique_ptr to be sent to foo:

1. `const unique_ptr<const int>`
2. `unique_ptr<const int>`
3. `const unique_ptr<int>`
4. `unique_ptr<int>`

If you specifically want to avoid for some reason 3 and 4 above, add const to T:

### Accept only const/non-const unique_ptr to const! (option b)

```
template<class T>
void foo(const unique_ptr<const T>& ptr) {
    // do something with ptr
}
```

#### Side note 1

You may overload "option a" and "option b" if to get different behavior for the cases where you can or cannot alter the pointed value.

#### Side note 2

If you do not want to make any changes to the pointed value in this function (never! whichever type of parameter we get!) -- **do not overload**.
With "option b", compiler won't allow to change the value we point at. Job done!
If you want to support all 4 cases, i.e. "option a", the function may still "accidentally" change the value we point to, e.g.

```
template<class T>
void foo(const unique_ptr<T>& ptr) {
    *ptr = 3;
}
```

however this should not be an issue if at least one caller has T that is actually const, the compiler will not like it in that case and help you get to the problem.
You may add such a caller in unit-test, something like:

```
    foo(make_unique<const int>(7)); // if this line doesn't compile someone
                                    // is changing value inside foo which is
                                    // not allowed!
                                    // do not delete the test, fix foo!
```

Code snippet: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a36795cdf305d4c7